# Error "invalid numeric value for data type numeric in...." while exporting database to excel

Tags: php, excel, export, numeric, phpspreadsheet

I've used phpspreadsheet to export data to excel.
This works fine but, sometime it gives the error as invalid numeric value for data type numeric in c:\xamp\htdocs\phpspreadsheet\vendor\phpoffice\spreadsheet\src\phpspeeadsheet\Cell\Cell.php:221
The image that I've attached is the error I get. Please help me.

````
session_start();
//php_spreadsheet_export.php

include 'C:/xampp/htdocs/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;


$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=IDC", "root", " ");

$school=$_SESSION['code'];
$name="name";
$query = "SELECT * FROM SCHOOL WHERE School='".$school."' AND Name!='".$name."'";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

if(isset($_POST["export"]))
{
 $file = new Spreadsheet();

 $active_sheet = $file->getActiveSheet();

 $active_sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Name');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Phone');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'DOB');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Father');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'Mother');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('F1', 'Address');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('G1', 'Blood');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('H1', 'Admission');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('I1', 'Photo link');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('J1', 'Class');
 $active_sheet->setCellValue('K1', 'Section');
 
 $count = 2;

 foreach($result as $row)
 {
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('A' . $count, $row["Name"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('B' . $count, $row["Phone"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('C' . $count, $row["DOB"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('D' . $count, $row["Father"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('E' . $count, $row["Mother"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('F' . $count, $row["Address"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('G' . $count, $row["Blood"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('H' . $count, $row["Adm_no"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('I' . $count, $row["Photo_link"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('J' . $count, $row["Class"]);
   $active_sheet->setCellValue('K' . $count, $row["Section"]);
   

   $count = $count + 1;
 }

 $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($file, $_POST["file_type"]);

 $file_name = time() . '.' . strtolower($_POST["file_type"]);

 $writer->save($file_name);

 header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');

 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");

 readfile($file_name);

 unlink($file_name);

 exit;

}

?> ```

This is the code and it works fine for all data except for this error.
````

Answer (score 1):

I got the error solved. The error was that, the numbers had a space at the end and was not matching the data type detected by value binder. So I set the data type as string.
Here is the changed code, if it will help anyone who is facing similar trouble.

```
$active-sheet->setCellValueExplicit( 'B'. $count, $row["phone"],\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

I got this answer from
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/